# backbone view not rendering on pagecreate event

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

Am building a mobile web app with jquery mobile, backbone, and require.js to make it modular.
I have an html page that has this;

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>DoIt</title>
  <link href="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script  charset="utf-8" src="jqm/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script  charset="utf-8" src="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script  charset="utf-8" src="libs/require.js" data-main="app"></script>

</head>
```

my app.js file looks like this

```
//Require.js configuration
require.config({
    paths: {
        'underscore': 'libs/underscore-min',
        'backbone': 'libs/backbone-min',
        'text': 'libs/text'
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});

require(['backbone', 'views/main'], function (Backbone, AppView) {
    'use strict';
     var view = new AppView();

     $(document).bind('pagecreate', function () {
        view.render(); 
     });
});
```

and this the template for the view

```
 <script type="text/html" id="app-view-tmpl">
    <div id="task-creator">
        <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="Enter a task">
        <button data-role="button" data-theme="b">
            Create task
        </button>
    </div>
      </script>
```

I using the 'pagecreate' event to trigger the rendering of the view.
The view doesnt render but other details i set to be logged to the console on initialization of the view are logged.
Am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know little about backbone.js but are you "refreshing" your widgets after building them?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-methods.html

`$("#myListView").listview("refresh");`

or

`$("#myButton").button("refresh");`

This should be part of your `pagecreate` logic. It would be helpful to get some additional details on your templates.

Comment: Am using underscore templates

Comment: Can you share your template? jQuery Mobile is highly dependent on markup and you haven't provided any. Thanks,